# Scan HashMap with string key

Tags: java, string, excel, hashmap, cycle

I stored an Excel row into `HashMap<String,String>` where the key is the coordinate of Excel cell (e.g. AA, AB, AC...).
Now I have to read this cell from map to then store into database. In paricualr I need the values from AA-CR and from DA to end of HashMap (HashMap.size).

How can I scan these fields given that I have to use key value and not integer?

***Further details***: the row number is not important because I work with one row at a time, so I have cell from A to for example GF. Now I have in a HashMap this information: key=A and value=Cella1 etc... A lot of fields are mapped singularly like this `value=actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.unladenWeight.getCoordinate()+index)`
where index is the current row.
The field where I have problem is those from  AA-CR because it would be dumb using one enum for each cell, so I would like to iterate from AA to CR and from DA to end of map.

Comment: Let me get this right.. You have a map that maps `A1 -> _value_`, `A2 -> _value_`, etc. And you are trying to get the whole row of AA (ie. AA1, AA2, AA3....) for example, by using the string `AA` (without the number)? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Use a LinkedHashMap and its Iterator, checking the values of the keys as you iterate though it? Performance will probably be poor.

Comment: Use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap` and then check what [`#subMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) can do for you.

Comment: I have updated my question with further informations